# Alex, Bethany, Carlos place blocks into boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Alex, Bethany, and Carlos are playing a game. In the game, there are $5$ completely empty boxes, and each person has $5$ blocks that are red, blue, yellow, green, and purple. Each of the people take turns placing all $5$ of their blocks (randomly) into a random box, and they will win the game if at least one box receives $3$ blocks of the same color. If the probability that the group will win is $\frac{m}{n},$ find $m + n.$

I noted that the decisions of the first player (assume its Alex) didn't matter, as the probability would be symmetric either way. I also noted that as long as one box had three of the same blocks, the three people would win and the other boxes would essentially be pointless. Therefore, I started counting the amount of ways Bethany and Carlos could place their blocks so that the three people would win. This gave me $$\binom{5}{1} * \binom{5}{1} \cdot 4! * \binom{5}{1} * 4! = 72000.$$ However, this answer felt a little bit off, so I wanted to ask somebody else to check if my answer was correct or not. Thanks!

Comment: It is certainly off... Now, before we can continue... we should clarify things.  You say "they place their blocks randomly into a random box."  What does this mean exactly?  You use factorials in your attempt... does this imply that each person places their five blocks into five separate boxes such that no box received more than one of their blocks and each of the $5!$ such choices for each person is equally likely?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification! Could you explain where my logic went awry?

Comment: Under that interpretation, then yes Alex's choices don't matter.  We can base everything off of whether the following players matched or didn't match Alex's choices.  For this, note that given an initial arrangement by Alex, there will be $(5!)^2$ equally likely arrangements.  Now, consider the events $R,B,Y,G,P$ that the red blocks all lined up, blue blocks all lined up, etc...  Apply inclusion-exclusion over these.  "*Could you explain where my logic went awry?*"  You didn't consider the possibility of multiple boxes all containing three matching blocks and have overcounted.

Comment: Ah, so I should subtract out the cases where two boxes have three matching blocks, then add the cases where three boxes have three matching blocks, and etc etc.

Comment: Yes.  Finish the problem by noting they asked you to calculate the probability, not just the count, express the probability in simplest reduced form, and add the numerator and denominator for the final answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but the probability I got ($\frac{3323}{144000}$) seems awfully large, so I'm not sure if the problem is my numerator or my denominator. For my numerator I got $39876$ and for my denominator I got $(5!)^3.$

Comment: Use $(5!)^2$ as the denominator as we don't care how Alex's choices went out.  We base all of our counting not on "box 1, box 2, etc..." but instead on "box where Alex put red, box where Alex put blue, etc..."  As for the numerator, $5\cdot (4!)^2-10\cdot (3!)^2+10\cdot (2!)^2-5\cdot (1!)^2+1$.  That should get you to $\frac{71}{400}$